# asp.net how to understand the 24-hour format

Tags: c#

I have a kind of data obtained from SQL server to end my time was 0:00:00 hours and now I want asp.net understand that time is 24 hours a day. can someone help me with

Comment: Do you have expected input and expected output vs the actual output? It will be best if you could provide all those info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would asp.net understand it? You know it, you tell asp to consider it a 24 hour format.

Use `ParseExact` to cast date:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(yourSqlDate, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss") //"HH" means 24-hour format
```

Comment: I have 2 1 hook time is 00:00:00 begin is at 0 am and I want to hook the 2nd end it is interpreted as 24 hours or as 23:59:59 I used this to my library lightning DatePair.js time time. but it's only a 30 minute time period alone